# Multi-Query Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are several tables in the database: films, persons and creators. Creators has two foreign keys to films and persons, as well as the fields "Character of participation" (director, actor, composer, etc.) and "Role" (see CREATE TABLE statements below). I would like to display a list of films in which the director is at the same time performing one of the main roles, indicating his last name and the role he played.

```
create table films (
film_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
film_name varchar(20) not null,
film_studio varchar(25) not null,
film_year int not null,
film_country varchar(20) null,
film_length tinyint not null,
film_genre varchar(15) not null,
constraint PK_films primary key(film_id),
);

create table persons (
person_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
person_name varchar(50) not null,
person_bday date not null,
person_dday date,
constraint PK_persons primary key(person_id),
);

create table creators (
creator_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
creator_film tinyint not null,
creator_person tinyint not null,
creator_who varchar(20) not null,
creator_role varchar(20),
constraint PK_creators primary key(creator_id),
constraint FK_CF foreign key(creator_film) references films(film_id),
constraint FK_CP foreign key(creator_person) references persons(person_id),
constraint CH_Who check(creator_who='director' or creator_who='actor' or creator_who='composer'),
);

insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film1', 'Studio1', 2018, 'USA', 100, 'Genre1')
insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film2', 'Studio2', 2018, 'USA', 120, 'Genre2')
insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film3', 'Studio3', 2000, 'England', 90, 'Genre3')

insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('John Smitt', '1988-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Mel Gibson
', '1988-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Miley Cyrus', '2001-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Deadpool', '1999-12-12', null)

insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who) values (1, 1, 'Director')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (1, 1, 'Actor', 'Main')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (2, 3, 'Actor', 'Secondary')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (3, 4, 'Actor', 'Secondary')
```

Desired result is: Film1 John Smith Main

Comment: Please translate your question.  Stack Overflow is an english-language site.

Comment: You need far more than translation I am afraid. You need a lot of details which are not present at this point.

Comment: I don't speak spanish. Try [there](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @Cid that isn't Spanish, it is Russian.

Comment: I don't speak Russian neither, that's why I gave a link to Russian version of SO :)

Comment: Thanks for the table definitions. Can you post a few rows of sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Posting the DDL is a great start. Now please add some sample data as DML (insert statements), desired results and your current attempt.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that there is a Russian version of SO
And in fact I can only read English.
thanks, now I will be more gratuitous to make up questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9211f/6

```
SELECT 
films.film_name,
persons.person_name,
actor.creator_role
FROM creators director
INNER JOIN creators actor
ON director.creator_person = actor.creator_person
   AND actor.creator_who = 'Actor'
LEFT JOIN films
ON director.creator_film = films.film_id
LEFT JOIN persons
ON director.creator_person = persons.person_id
WHERE director.creator_who = 'Director'
```